# Setting property of a subview

Tags: iphone, subview

I have a UIView containing among others a subview.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    geopointView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 350, 100, 80)] ;
    UIButton *SaveButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain] ;
    SaveButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 100, 40) ;
    [geopointView addSubview:SaveButton];
}
```

I want to set userInteractionEnabled property of this subview in another method.

How can I dot it? thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: How can you access Savebutton which is local member of viewDidLoad. Have it as a class member.

Comment: this looks ok. Does it not compile or do you get an error at runtime? Make sure that your `anotherMethod` is really called.

Comment: It gave compiler  error. I have two buttons saveButton and SaveGeoButton which caused confusion, sorry for this. I have edited question agaiin.

Comment: The compiler-error would be nice ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare the savebutton in the header file. You have declared it as a local member.Have it declared as a global variable.

Comment: is it possible to declare it locally and then access as part of parent View. because at one point or another I will have to many buttons and it is better if they are declared locally and released when necessary.

Comment: booleanBoy is right. You have to store pointers to the buttons somewhere if you want to access these buttons in other methods. If there are many of them just use a `NSMutableArray` and dont forget to release them when the view is not needed any more.

Comment: you need not release buttons....you need not release any object unless u call any of the methods like alloc,retain,copy etc... so i guess there wont be trouble of memory leaks